# What is the Hadoop ecosystem and how does Apache Spark fit in?

Tags: hadoop

I'm having a lot of trouble grasping what exactly a 'Hadoop ecosystem' is conceptually. I understand that you have some data processing tasks that you want to run and so you use MapReduce to split the job up into smaller pieces but I'm unsure about what people mean when they say 'Hadoop Ecosystem'. I'm also unclear as to what the benefits of Apache Spark are and why this is seen as so revolutionary? If it's all in-memory calculation, wouldn't that just mean that you would need higher RAM machines to run Spark jobs? How is Spark different than writing some parallelized Python code or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather broad - the Hadoop ecosystem is a wide range of technologies that either support Hadoop MapReduce, make it easier to apply, or otherwise interact with it to get stuff done.

Examples:

- The Hadoop Distributed Filesystem ([HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html)) stores data to be processed by MapReduce jobs, in a scalable redundant distributed fashion.
- [Apache Pig](https://pig.apache.org/) provides a language, Pig Latin, for expressing data flows that are compiled down into MapReduce jobs
- [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) provides an SQL-like language for querying huge datasets stored in HDFS

There are many, many others - see for example https://hadoopecosystemtable.github.io/

[Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) is *not* all in-memory; it can perform calculations in-memory if enough RAM is available, and can spill data over to disk when required.

It is particularly suitable for iterative algorithms, because data from the previous iteration can remain in memory. It provides a very different (and much more concise) programming interface, compared to plain Hadoop. It can provide some [performance advantages](http://databricks.com/blog/2014/11/05/spark-officially-sets-a-new-record-in-large-scale-sorting.html) even when the work is mostly done on disk rather than in-memory. It supports [streaming](https://spark.apache.org/streaming/) as well as batch jobs. It can be used interactively, unlike Hadoop.

Spark is relatively easy to install and play with, compared to Hadoop, so I suggest you give it a try to understand it better - for experimentation it can run off a normal filesystem and does not require HDFS to be installed. See the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html).